# php session for redirecting user to empty form page

Tags: php, sql, session

i'm new to php and got a problem with php session.
i have a form and when the user press submit button, i want to show an alert, then redirect it to the empty form page. but my code doesn't work:

```
session_start();

if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {

if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    echo "Records added successfully.";
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
} else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql." . mysqli_error($connection));
    header("Location: index.php");

}
```

Comment: `alert()` is not a PHP function (unless you've defined it yourself, in code accessible by this)

Comment: what can i use instead of it?

Comment: That really depends on what you're actually wanting to achieve. You could make your request via ajax and then use javascript to display the appropriate message based on the result. Or you could redirect to index.php and include a flag parameter that indicates whether the operation was successful or not, and then on index.php you check that flag and show the related message. Too many options to give a specific answer. Do some more learning about the difference between PHP, HTML, and Javascript.

Comment: thanks, but the code doesn't work even with using echo

Comment: That's because you don't understand what the `header()` function actually does. [You can't `echo` before `header()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/1505169)

Answer (score 0):

Alert is a javascript function.

If you want to show a Javascript aler you can use this code:

```
echo '<script>alert("Records added successfully.")</script>';
```

But in you case if you will show alert page redirect will not work.

If you want to show a success message on `index.php` page then store that message into session like `$_SESSION['message']`.

On `index.php` page check if session contains message then show message and remove it from session, so it can it not appear again. e.g:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['message'])){
  echo $_SESSION['message'];
  unset($_SESSION['message']);
}
```